# Personal Tax Return software for Linux?

Tags: software, income-tax

I'm looking for something like TaxCut or TurboTax but I can't find indications that they run on Linux. I still have a Windows machine somewhere but I'd rather not have to dig it out. I *am* willing to pay for software as long as it's not to crazy a price.

Does something like that exist?

---

Edit: Another requirement is that it must be a local program (so I can archive both the software and the data).

Comment: do none of the web based options meet your needs?

Comment: No. Anything on-line is out.

Comment: Isn't there software to run window applications on Linux? I thought Wine was one.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer mere seconds you beat me by!
It's much more complicated but have you thought about trying http://www.winehq.org/ to run native windows applications on your linux box?

Comment: ha. I've written long answers onlt to see "new answer posted" pop up, and it's similar. I know of, but never used, Wine.

Answer (score 3):

[TurboTax online](http://www.turbotax.com/lp/ty11/ppc/trusted-free-tax.jsp?cid=ppc_gg_nb_stan_dk_us_hv-tx-sftwr-fr&adid=9824947389&skw=free%20tax%20software&kw=web%20tax%20software&ven=gg&) works via Firefox (i.e. it is a cloud-based service.) I don't think any downloaded software is available directly for Linux.

Comment: I added this before BCS's comment about needing to be local.  I am going to leave this up for now.

Comment: +1 but not for me. Also, I'd actually rather pay for the software on a CD as that's easier to archive.

Comment: As of 2013, it seems TurboTax is arbitrarily [blocks Linux users](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/5645/has-anyone-compared-an-in-person-tax-advisor-to-software-like-turbo-tax) (tho it is not without workarounds).

Answer (score 0):

I used H&R Block this year 2013 to do my 2012 taxes and it was a snap!  Ubuntu 12.10 with Firefox 20 and everything worked great!  Although it is not listed as one of the "supported" platforms, Firefox breezed through the application without any problems.  I used the deluxe version of H&R to calculate my mortgage and home business deductions, but I would guess any of the H&R versions work.

Comment: The post has the explicit requirement that excludes cloud/web online services.